# How to define static Arraylist in thread safe environment

Tags: java, static, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

How to define static Arraylist in thread safe environment. I have tried synchronized keyword but I heard using Automic classes from java concurrent package is a best solution for static arraylist. Can anybody tell how to declare and use the static arraylist in safe manner?

**Update:**

in my code i have an static list to maintain the details of your those logging in the application

```
private static List<UserSessionForm> userSessionList = new ArrayList<UserSessionForm>();
```

during login and accessing homepage(all time home page got accessed) checking for userdetails in userSessionList , if not availble adding the details in userSessionList and during logout removing the userdetails from the list.
during login

```
if (getUserSessionIndex(uform)!=-1) {
            this.getUserSession().add(usform);
            this.getSession().setAttribute("customerId", getCustomer_id());
        }
```

during logout

```
  public void logout(){
     int index = getUserSessionIndex(usform);
        //if user is  already loginned, remove that user from the usersession list
        if (index != -1) {
            UserAction.getUserSession().remove(index);
        }
   }

  private int getUserSessionIndex(UserSessionForm usform) {
    int index = -1;
    int tmp_index = 0;
    for (UserSessionForm tmp : UserAction.getUserSession()) {
        if (usform.equals(tmp)) {
            if (usform.getUserlogin_id() == tmp.getUserlogin_id()) {
                index = tmp_index;
                break;
            }
        }
        tmp_index += 1;
    }
    return index;
}
```

so there is a chance to read and write request takes place in same time

Comment: It depends: will the `ArrayList` be accessed concurrently? Will it be written concurrently? Will it be mutable?

Comment: updated with actual coding what im using

Answer (score 4):

It depends a lot on how you are going to use it. There are several options:

- use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) - this is a modern concurrent implementation, best suited when there is relatively few writes and lots of reads
- use a synchronized wrapper obtained via [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) - it allows you to access the "original" unsynchronized list from e.g. within the containing object, but provide a thread safe access to the "outside world".

`Vector` is an old, obsolete collection implementation, which should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 3):

The `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` is "a thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations `add`, `set`, and so on are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array".